# How to change structure of subversion repository?

Tags: svn

I'm a newbie with Subversion, so I don't now if this is a dumb question:

I've inherited a subversion repository with a flat structure with no /trunk /tags /branches top level).

I'd like re-structure it so that it follows the

```
/trunk
/tags
/branches
```

layout.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21):

Especially if you're using Subversion 1.4, see this answer for an alternative:

[svn: replace trunk with branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331388/svn-replace-trunk-with-branch#331574).

Otherwise, `move` is the simplest way to achieve the restructuring.  As @JoelFan said, `move` will work on directories, so you can perform this operation without a working copy:

```
svn mkdir --quiet --message "Restructuring" http://svnhost/svnrepos/trunk
svn mkdir --quiet --message "Restructuring" http://svnhost/svnrepos/tags
svn mkdir --quiet --message "Restructuring" http://svnhost/svnrepos/branches
```

then, appropriate `move` commands for your sources:

```
svn move --message "Restructuring" http://svnhost/svnrepos/dir01 http://svnhost/svnrepos/trunk/dir01
```

Note: If the existing repository has a structure like:

```
/repos
    /projectA
        /branches
        /tags
        /trunk
    /projectB
        /branches
        /tags
        /trunk
```

I'd suggest leaving it that way - it would make separating the projects into separate repositories very straightforward if for some reason you need to do so.

Comment: Is this the ACCEPTED answer?

Comment: @Xofo SVN has moved far beyond version 1.4.  For older versions, yes, this answer is correct and works.  Newer versions?  I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

svn move [(1.4)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) [(1.7)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) can operate on directories within the repository, so you shouldn't need to check out or check in anything.

Answer (score 4):

If you're use TortoiseSVN:

1. Create empty required directories (`/trunk /tags /branches`)
2. Commit them.
3. In context menu open `TortoiseSVN > Repo-Browser` , where simply select all(except `/trunk /tags /branches`) and drag-n-drop to `/trunk` directory (all inside of Repo-Browser window)
4. Pres `Ok > Submit > Ok`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Just make the desired top level structure, add those directories with svn add. Do a checkin (svn ci) and then move stuff to the desired places with svn move. The checkin in the middle may not even be necessary, but that's they way I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use the svn move command!