# Is it possible to pre-define new project structure in TortoiseSVN/VisualSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Is it possible with TortoiseSVN/VisualSVN to pre-define a project structure so you can simply click "new project" or similar?

e.g. in VisualSVN you can Create new project and you get `trunk/branch/tag` folders automatically.

However, I'd like to do the same in TortoiseSVN (so users can do this without needing VisualSVn acess)

AND/OR

I'd like to pre-set more folders than this, so e.g.

```
trunk/docs
trunk/src
trunk/database
trunk/elephant
```

etc...

is any of this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361801/how-to-change-structure-of-subversion-repository

Comment: So: yes and no!  yes it is, but it requires a batch file/doing manaully.

Comment: @blue: Can you make this an answer and I'll tick it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Subversion stores your versioned history using, at the very least, binary differencing algorithms and data compression (optionally in a completely opaque database system), attempting manual tweaks is unwise, if not quite difficult, and at any rate strongly discouraged. And once data has been stored in your repository, Subversion generally doesn't provide an easy way to remove that data.

for you, svn mkdir will do the job.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361801/how-to-change-structure-of-subversion-repository)

Answer (score 1):

With up-to-date VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN you get request about creating default layout after creating repository. Non-standard trees are not supported, but you can always write bat-file for this task