# Replace branch with trunk HEAD revision in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

I created a branch for my repository. Since then, I have made different changes in both branch and trunk. What I want to do now is to ignore whatever changes I made in the branch and copy the HEAD revision of the trunk to the branch. In a way, it's like re-creating the branch again, only with a more updated revision.

Changes in the branch will still be there if I merge trunk to branch and that is not the desired outcome.

I can svn delete the entire branch and create a new one but I don't want to lose my changes in branch, just in case.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/331388/395718) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/587603/395718). Answers deal with opposite direction, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch out from the trunk's head revision and just let the old branch be as it is. Hence, you have the changes you made in the old branch, just in case you need them back, and the new branch will be as you desired.