# SVN Release branch to Trunk

Tags: svn, devops

Which way is the right to promote a release branch to trunk (Production)?

I can del my trunk and move my branch and rename to trunk, as described here
[svn: replace trunk with branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331388/svn-replace-trunk-with-branch)

And I can merge from my trunk to my release branch as some other posts here says.

Which one seems to be better for a DevOps environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methodologically speaking, when you delete a branch and move the new one ("blessing"), you create revisions for these actions (the deletion is one commit, the move is another).
When you merge a branch, you have a single commit denoting your operation ("merge branch 'X' to trunk).
This means that it's more efficient to merge the branch and it creates a readable timeline that shows the operations happening on your branches (branch created off trunk at some point, merged back at some other point in time).
If you delete the trunk and rename the development branch as the new trunk, the history is less evident and requires explicit scrutiny to understand what has happened.
Technically speaking, both approaches are equivalent and you can intermingle them freely. Do what is easier for you.